# Threshold of resistance against Linear Cryptanalysis

Tags: aes, rijndael, linear-cryptanalysis

In the [AES proposal](https://www.cs.miami.edu/home/burt/learning/Csc688.012/rijndael/rijndael_doc_V2.pdf), the last sentence on page 30 it is said:

> To be resistant against LC, it is a necessary condition that there are no linear trails with a correlation coefficient higher than 2^(n/2)

I know that the correlation coefficient can have values in the range [-1,1]. Moreover, In the same proposal, they mentioned that

> we prove that there are no 4-round linear trails with a correlation above 2^–75

My question is: do they mean "To be resistant against LC, it is a necessary condition that there are no linear trails with a correlation coefficient higher than **2^(-n/2)**"

Answer (score 2):

It is just a simple typo. The whole paragraph from page 30 makes this clear:

[image]

It is the correlation that should be no larger than $2^{n/2}$ and the *correlation coefficient* is obtained by the normalization of the correlation by the maximal value possible, i.e., division by $2^{n}$, thus explaining the reference to $2^{-75}$ elsewhere in the context of correlation coefficient.